# How can I check if sata controller supports hotswap?

Tags: hardware, storage, sata, removable-storage

Is there a programmatic/generic way to check if sata controller supports howswap?

I'd love this question to be generic, so people can apply answer regardless of controller they have.

However, in lack of generic way, here is my `lspci -v` for *Silicon Image, Inc. SiI 3114* of [Delock 4 port with Raid on PCI no. 70154](http://www.delock.com/produkte/G_70154/merkmale.html):

```
04:00.0 RAID bus controller: Silicon Image, Inc. SiI 3114 [SATALink/SATARaid] Serial ATA Controller (rev 02)
        Subsystem: Silicon Image, Inc. SiI 3114 [SATALink/SATARaid] Serial ATA Controller
        Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 64, IRQ 18
        I/O ports at c040 [size=8]
        I/O ports at c030 [size=4]
        I/O ports at c020 [size=8]
        I/O ports at c010 [size=4]
        I/O ports at c000 [size=16]
        Memory at f7c80000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
        Expansion ROM at f7c00000 [disabled] [size=512K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: sata_sil
        Kernel modules: sata_sil
```

Comment: If it was exported anywhere, I'd expect it to be in the `/sys` tree. There's a [hotplug-capable port](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/ata/ahci.h#L186) constant in the AHCI header, but nothing uses it. Other devices I have to hand don't export the information either, AFAICS (checked on LSI SAS HBAs, LSI and Adaptec SCSI HBAs).